# How to determine if an user has entered an incorrect input?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I was looking this site for data validation:

http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

And it sounds great the validation. But for example I realized you can only validate data when the input is correct, if there's a way to set a message when the input is not correct.

I.E. If I have a property Age where is an int, I want to custom the error message to display where the user wrote "a" in a textBox.

I mean, Age property must validate two things, the input will be correct and the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Data-Binding, you need to validate your input with validation rules:

```
<TextBox Name="tb_act_name"
                         Style="{StaticResource formTextBox}"
                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}">
                  <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="act_name"
                             Mode="TwoWay"
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                             ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                      <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:fieldNullOrEmpty ErrorMessage="Enter Client Name" />
                      </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                  </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

You would simply add more rules in the Binding.ValidationRules section. This is quite a big subject so you may wish to check out MSDN WPF Validation for more help.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: It's not actually necessary to use ValidationRules if the bound class itself supports IDataErrorInfo and updates it appropriately upon property set.

Comment: Yes but there are limitations to that approach, just trying to fast track the guy

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Karl Shifflett's approach](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mvvm/input-validation-ui-exceptions-model-validation-errors/)

Or you can also add (look at [WPF Validation for the whole form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104520/wpf-validation-for-the-whole-form)):

```
<TextBox.Text>
 <Binding Path="Age" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
  <Binding.ValidationRules>
    <rules:NumericRule />
  </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```