# WPF - How do I access the number of errors in the viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I have a single viewmodel representing my applications main view. This viewmodel contains an ObservableCollection of model objects which a grid on my view is bound to. Each item in the collection implements IDataErrorInfo which facilitates the standard WPF validation mechanism i.e an error in the model causes the view control to highlight red (in this instance a cell).

My problem is, I want to perform a piece of logic in the viewmodel which needs access to the number of errors on the page (or rather IF there are errors or not). I can't see a way to access this from within the viewmodel itself, all the WPF validation seems to be contained in the view, is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything "built in" to achieve this. One option is to expose a property on each model in the OC such as `IsValid`, which you would set from within the model's IDataErrorInfo indexed property. Your VM can then use a bit of Linq to check for any models in the OC where IsValid=false.

If you are intending to have your VM expose some kind of "PageHasErrors" property, then you'll probably need to have the VM subscribe to each model's PropertyChange event (specifically the `IsValid` property), assuming the model implements INPC. Within the VM's event handler you would then update the "PageHasErrors" property based on whether any of the models IsValid=false.

Comment: "which you would set from within the model's IDataErrorInfo indexed property" How would I do this? Each property is evaluated in turn, right? Not sure how I could set an `IsValid` property for the whole object.

Comment: There are a couple of creative solutions proposed in this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603243/idataerrorinfo-how-to-know-if-all-properties-are-valid